# How to allocate partition of more than 2TB?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I've installed a Windows 8.1 on a 3TB hard disk, creating an initial system partion with approx. 300GB. Now I'd like to create partitions on the remaining space, however Windows won't let me do it.

[image: screenshot]

I'm able to create a volume on the 1755,03 GB part, but not on the remaining 746,52 GB. I've tried to create a NTFS partition using gParted, but that failed because of 'ms-dos systems don't support file storages larger than 2 TB'.

Is there a way to allocate the unassigned space without loosing data?

Answer (score 2):

From the scalability section of the Wikipedia article on [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Scalability):

> Because partition tables on master boot record (MBR) disks only
>   support partition sizes up to 2 TB, dynamic or [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) volumes must be
>   used to create NTFS volumes over 2 TB. Booting from a GPT volume to a
>   Windows environment requires a system with [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) and 64-bit support.

If you right-click on the left side of the area you show on your screenshot, i.e., in the area where you see "2794,52 GB", if you are using [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) for controlling the partitions instead of [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) you will see the option "Convert to GPT Disk", though it will likely be grayed out since you already have partitions on the drive. If it is grayed out, you can backup the drive, wipe out all the partitions and then convert to GPT.

Alternatively, [How to Convert MBR to GPT Disk in Windows 8 / 7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk) indicates you can use [gptgen](http://gptgen.sourceforge.net/), which is free and available through [SourceForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge). The SourceForge description of the software states:

> Gptgen is a tool to non-destructively convert hard disks partitioned
>   in the common, "MSDOS-style" MBR scheme (including extended
>   partitions) to use a GUID partition table (GPT).

The article I referenced also indicates [AOMEI Partition Assistant Lite Edition](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/aomei-partition-assistant-home-edition-review-free-download) is "a free multifunction partition management software" which will allow you to "convert a disk with data into GPT or MBR style without data loss."

I've not tried either myself, so I can't speak from experience on their usage; I'd be sure I had everything backed up just in case something went terribly awry.